# how to clone a file input to another file input which is in hidden iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, file

i have a form which has a file input element and when the user selects the file i want to set the selected file to another file input which is in hidden iframe,

this is what is my form:

```
<form name="uploadForm" >
    <input type="file" id="fileone" name="fileone" value="" />
    <button type="button" id="attachement_upload" onclick="addFile()" >Upload</button>
</form>
<iframe id="FileUploadFrame" name="FileUploadFrame" src="" style="display: none; border: 0; width: 0; height: 0;">
    <form id="FileUploadForm" name="FileUploadForm" accept-charset="utf-8" target="FileUploadFrame" enctype="multipart/form-data" encoding="multipart/form-data" method="POST" action="CIMtrek_Regional_WhseForm_FileUpload">
        <input type="file" id="filetwo" name="filetwo" value="" />
    </form>
</iframe>
```

and my java script :

```
function addFile(){
    //this is where i want to clone the fileone to filetwo and submit the form which is in iframe
}
```

I have seen some thing like this but really don't know how to do :

```
$(".inputfield1").change(function(){
  var $this = $(this), $clone = $this.clone();
  $this.after(clone).appendTo(hiddenform);
});
```

Please help me to get this done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't (or shouldn't) be able to do this.  The `file` input type, given that it has direct access to the user's file system, has special security restrictions.  Most notably you cannot set the `value` of a `file` input in JavaScript, as this would allow you to do things like set it to something like `~/.ssh/id_rsa` and steal important data without the user being aware.  As a consequence, jQuery shouldn't be able to clone the `file` input because it can't set the value.

To get this to work you'll have to let the user click on the `file` input that is in the `iframe`, perhaps using some CSS positioning tricks to make it seem part of the page.  Alternatively, if your users typically have more modern browsers, you could use the [File API](http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/) and [upload the file with Ajax](http://robertnyman.com/2010/12/16/utilizing-the-html5-file-api-to-choose-upload-preview-and-see-progress-for-multiple-files/).