# append() in jquery does'nt append file second time

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have defined an input of type file and a hidden form below it,

```
<input type="file" name="attachment0" id="attachment0" custom-on-change="uploadfile" ng-show="attachFile" multiple/>
<form class="hidden" id="myForm" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="SupportRequest">                                 
</form>
```

"custom-on-change" is an angular directive that calls the function uploadfile() after choosing files. My javascript looks as shown below

```
var form = $('#myForm');
var n=0;
$scope.attachFile = true;

$scope.uploadfile = function() {                                        
                if(n == 0){
                var filein = $('#attachment0');
                form.append(filein);
                $('#attachment0').test();
                }
                else
                    {
                    if(n==1){
                    var temp = "attachment0" + '_' + n;
                    var file_in = $('#'+temp);
                    form.append(file_in);
                    $('#'+temp).test();}                        
                    }
            };

$.fn.test = function() {
                  return this.each(function(){
                    n++;
                    $(this).attr('id',   this.id + '_' + n);
                    $(this).attr('name', this.name + '_' + n);
                  });
            };
```

Am trying to append files twice to the form myForm. When i choose files second time, even after appending, i see that the previously appended input with id="attachment0" is not present in myForm and the input of id="attachment0_1" is present in the form. 
Here am trying to upload multiple files multiple times, that is why am dynamically changing the id of the input in test().
I want both input with id attachment0 and attachment0_1 in myForm.
Does anyone know how this can be fixed? And explain this behavior too.

Comment: Is there any error in browser's console?

Comment: Can I ask why you are using jQuery to update the UI when you are using AngularJS as well?

Comment: Hello all, I have updated the description. I was basically trying to upload multiple files multiple times, that is why i dynamically change the id of my input.

Answer (score 1):

Change your code from form.append(filein) to form.append($('#attachment0').clone()).

It work then. You should use .clone() method to copy elements .

.append() just moves the element from one place to another but for copying first create the copy of the element using .clone() and then append it to your form

Comment: But the file cannot be copied, check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14772947/how-to-clone-a-file-input-to-another-file-input-which-is-in-hidden-iframe

Answer (score 0):

looks like in `test` function you are replacing id,

```
$(this).attr('id',   this.id + '_' + n);
```

Answer (score 0):

Would is not be better to use `ng-repeat`? Something like this:

Controller:

```
$scope.files = [...] // list of files

$scope.uploadfile = function() {                                        
    // So stuff to get the file
    $scope.files.push(filein);
};
```

Html:

```
<!-- Inside the form -->
<div ng-repeat="file in files">{{file}}</div>
```

Comment: Am not trying to print the files here, am trying to append the input type of file to myForm.